# How do I reset my gem environment?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am currently unable to install any gems because I keep getting the follwiing error message

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::E045)
    Operation not supported - /home/rocker

I am using sudo command.
I believe the issue is in my gen env has info that is no longer correct

1. RubyGems Environment:

   - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
   - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174)
     [universal-darwin10.0]
   - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/rocker/ruby/gems
   - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
   - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/rocker/ruby/gems/bin
   - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

     - ruby
     - universal-darwin-10
   - GEM PATHS:

     - /home/rocker/ruby/gems
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
   - GEM CONFIGURATION:

     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gempath" => ["/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"]
     - "gem" => "--remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests"
     - "gemhome" => "/home/rocker/ruby/gems"
     - "rdoc" => "--inline-source --line-numbers"
   - REMOTE SOURCES:

     - http://rubygems.org/ the
   - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/rocker/ruby/gems
   - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/rocker/ruby/gems/bin
   - GEM PATHS:

     - /home/rocker/ruby/gems
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

all point to the a incorrect location( /home/rocker/), how do i change it

i have tried setting items in my path

export GEM_HOME=/Users/Digitalsleep01/Documents/Codeworks/codebase/Gems
export GEM_PATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the above commands with sudo.

Comment: sorry I am not clear what you are asking do you mean sudo export GEM_HOME=/Users/Digitalsleep01/Documents/Codeworks/codebase/Gems? that does not work

Comment: I figured it out, You have to edit ~/.gemrc that allowed me to edit the values in gem env